# Forbid any network activity until user initiates/finishes log in

Tags: windows, networking, administration

I'm testing a limiter network setup in the organization and I need to ensure that there will be no network available until user logs into system. There are other ways I could possibly tackle this issue, including server-side solutions, but I want to try to use as local and as simple as possible variants.

My original idea was to use either **Task Scheduler** or **Group Policy Shutdown** to basically disable network interface (and then re-enable at log on):

`netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" admin=enable` (cmd)

or

`Disable-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet`

However, perhaps unsurprisingly, neither **netsh** nor **powershell** can properly run, I assume because at that point of system env. state only basic OS core features and functions available.

Any ideas how else can I approach this?

Comment: How will the user authenticate to Active Directory if there is no network available?

Comment: This is not necessary in the current setup.

Comment: If your threat model includes people connecting their own devices to your network, then this is what 802.1X a.k.a the extensible authentication protocol over LANs, or EAPoL, is for. Your Ethernet switches (or Wi-Fi APs) allow no traffic other than authentication traffic until the device has authenticated itself to the network.

Comment: No, it just that simple - I need to forbid any network activity on workstation UNTIL after user logged in locally.